# Django: Getting the offset of an object in a QuerySet

Tags: django, database, model, django-queryset

I have two models, one is a question text and the second is a user- and question-specific answer. I a user has answered many questions, given a question, how can I find the index of the respective answer? Index meaning the number of previous answers/the position of the given answer.

More specifically, when I query the following:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Question(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.TextField()


def getIndexOfAnswer(user, question):
    answer = user.answer_set.filter(user=user, question=question).all().order_by("pk")
    return answer.???index()???
```

how can I get the index of an answer for a given user (say, ordered by PrimaryKey)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it!

```
def getIndexOfAnswer(user, question):
    answer = user.answer_set.filter(question=question).get()
    return user.answer_set.filter(pk__lte=answer.pk).count() - 1
```